# Qt - Program still running in task manager when I close window during qApp->processEvents()

Tags: c++, qt

My application draws and labels to an image. When the window is closed while waiting for input, the application still runs in the background. Here is an example of my function that captures a label. Am I missing something to make the program quit properly?

```
 void CustomMainWindow::CaptureLabel(void){

     connect(measurementLabel,
             SIGNAL(mousePressSignal()),
             this,
             SLOT(mouseLabel()),
             Qt::DirectConnection
             );

     m_MouseCount = 0;
     m_CurrentLabel = cv::Point2f(0.0, 0.0);

     while(m_MouseCount < 1){
         qApp->processEvents();

     }

     disconnect(measurementLabel,
             SIGNAL(mousePressSignal()),
             this,
             SLOT(mouseLabel())
             );
 }
```

Comment: `setQuitOnLastWindowClosed()` is stay true?

Comment: The solution is simple. **Never** call `processEvents`. The `while` loop is a bad example of pseudo-synchronous code. Don't write like that. Instead, put the click counter in a slot, or use a state machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily use a state machine to guide you through the state changes. This will remove the need for the horrible pseudo-synchronous hacks you resort to.

```
class CustomMainWindow : ... {
  QStateMachine m_CaptureLabelMachine;
  ...
};

void CustomMainWindow::CaptureLabel(void){
  if (!m_CaptureLabelMachine.findChild<QFinalState*>()) {
    // build the state machine
    auto machine = &m_CaptureLabelMachine;
    auto s1 = new QState(machine), s2 = new QFinalState(machine);
    machine->setInitialState(s1);
    s1->addTransition(measurementLabel, SIGNAL(mousePressSignal()), s2);
    connect(s1, &QState::entered, [this]{
      connect(measurementLabel, SIGNAL(mousePressSignal()), SLOT(mouseLabel()));
      m_MouseCount = 0;
      m_CurrentLabel = cv::Point2f(0.0, 0.0);
    });
    connect(s2, &QState::entered, [this]{
      disconnect(measurementLabel, SIGNAL(mousePressSignal()), SLOT(mouseLabel()));
    });
  }
  m_CaptureLabelMachine.start();
}
```

Comment: What does the `if (!m_CaptureLabelMachine.findChild<QFinalState>())` do?

Comment: I have attempted to implement your code (but without lambda expressions) and it appears to continue to rebuild the state machines but not wait until execution is finished before moving on. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The check you're referring to checks that the machine has been built - it must have a `QFinalState` as its child if so. There was a typo, it should be a pointer type - that's why it didn't work. NB, without lambda expressions you can put the two blurbs into slots in `CustomMainWindow`.

Comment: And, of course, this code will not wait for anything - it's not supposed to wait. It's asynchronous. The two code blurbs in the lambdas get executed at proper moments in time - that's all that has to happen for it to work, assuming the rest of your code is OK. They'll be invoked when the state transitions happen. The calls to the blurbs/slots will happen with the `measurementLabel->event(QEvent*)` on the call stack, as these are direct connections.

Comment: The error I get in regards to your check is "no match for 'operator!'(operand type is 'QFinalState'). I did use the '->' instead of '.' Could there be another function to check if these exist?

Comment: Also, given that my code is currently designed using a number of steps (which rely on processEvents) that collect user input one after the other has finished, what would be a proper method be to achieve this using Finite States? Would it be something like a StepClass() that connects the FSmachine finishedSignal() to the start of the next step?

Comment: Can I use the s2 enter() signal to return from `CustomMainWindow::CaptureLabel()` ?

Comment: @Langleson You must stop thinking in terms of synchronous code. What happens is asynchronous. You have blurbs, or actions, that must be completed when the state of the system changes. You must familiarize yourself with hierarchical finite state machines - look at Qt examples. It doesn't matter how many actions you have. Each step should be one or more states - depending on what's going on. The action performed upon entry or exit of a state should be short and must not block. Use lamndas or individual slots, you don't need an entire class for a step. All of this can be done without subclassing.

Comment: @Langleson Perhaps you should amend your question and turn it into something that you really wish to ask: how to design asynchronous code in Qt. Tell us what is your task - what are you trying to do - show the bad sync code you've got, and we'll help you do it the right way instead.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to remedy this using a close event and a flag within the while loop.

```
 void CustomMainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *)
 {
     m_cancelFlag = true;
 }

 void CustomMainWindow::CaptureLabel(void){

     connect(measurementLabel,
             SIGNAL(mousePressSignal()),
             this,
             SLOT(mouseLabel()),
             Qt::DirectConnection
             );

     m_MouseCount = 0;
     m_CurrentLabel = cv::Point2f(0.0, 0.0);

     while(m_MouseCount < 1){
     qApp->processEvents();
     if(m_cancelFlag){
         disconnect(measurementLabel,
                 SIGNAL(mousePressSignal()),
                 this,
                 SLOT(mouseLabel())
                 );
         return;
     }
 }
disconnect(measurementLabel,
        SIGNAL(mousePressSignal()),
        this,
        SLOT(mouseLabel())
        );
}
```

Comment: Your loop is kind of CPU intensive. Perhaps you should use `qApp->processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);`; look it up in the documentation.

Comment: This is a horrible hack.

Comment: @KubaOber, you should try to be less condescending when you educate.

Comment: @HamishMoffatt, wow, the difference in CPU % is incredible. 25% before vs a fraction of a % with QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents

Comment: It's still a horrible hack. It's not condescending, it's how the code is. You should not encourage coding the way the question was coded. It's a pseudo-synchronous mess that introduces reentrancy problems and should be discouraged. If you think you need to use `processEvents`, you're wrong 99% of the time. I've just checked - in four 50k+ line Qt applications that are heavy on responsiveness and asynchronous processing of all sorts, I have no `processEvents` calls. I believe that Qt should have a "-cleanapi" config flag to turn off most `exec`, `waitFor...` and `processEvents`.